# Why this is Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, stochastic-differential-equations

$$ \log W_t = \int_0^t \left(r + \pi(\mu-r) - \frac{1}{2} \pi^2\sigma^2\right) du + \int_0^t \pi \sigma  \,d Z_u $$

And that $$\log W_t \sim \operatorname{Normal} (\left(r + \pi(\mu-r) - \frac{1}{2}\pi^2\sigma^2\right), \pi^2\sigma^2)$$

I don't see how come this can be converted onto Normal distribution (i.e., I don't see how can first line be converted onto second line), can you please help?

Comment: I think you've missed a factor of $t$ from each of the mean & variance.

Comment: please see slides #14 here: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cme241/lecture_slides/UtilityTheoryForRisk.pdf

Comment: They've missed the factor, then.

Comment: $t$ is missing, you mean the second line?

Comment: Yes. Consider the $\sigma\to0^+$ limit. Really, the crux of the problem is $\int_0^tdZ_u\sim N(0,\,t)$.

Comment: I see. Do you know how does the first term integral gets transfer to the mean of the normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\int_0^tdZ_u\sim N(0,\,t)$, a deterministic $\mu$ satisfies$$\mu+\int_0^t\pi\sigma dZ_u=\mu+\pi\sigma\int_0^tdZ_u=\mu+\pi\sigma N(0,\,t)=N(\mu,\,\pi^2\sigma^2t).$$In this case, $\mu=\int_0^tcdu=ct$ for $u$-independent integrand $c=r+\pi(\mu-r)-\frac12\pi^2\sigma^2$.